# c malloc assertion failed when allocating memory

Tags: c, malloc

```
    typedef struct textNode{ //basically contains a line + link
        char* line;
        int sLength; //length of string
        struct textNode* next; 
    } tNode; 

    struct textbuffer{
        int size; //number of lines in the text buffer
        int totalsLength;
        tNode* head; 
        tNode* tail;
    };

char *dumpTB (TB tb){

    int stringLength = tb->totalsLength; //sLength is 
    char* text = malloc(sizeof(char) * stringLength+1);

    int i = 0;
    int x = 0; //string index

    tNode* curr = tb->head;

    while(curr != NULL){

        while(curr->line[x] != '\n'){
            printf("%d", i);
            text[i] = curr->line[x];
            printf("%c\n", text[i]);

            i++;
            x++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", i);
        text[i] = '\n';
        printf("%c", text[i]);
        i++;

        x = 0; 
        curr = curr->next; 
    }

    text[tb->totalsLength] = '\0';

    return text;
}
```

So I had print statements around my code where I malloced in dumpTB and it seems to throw a sysmalloc assertion failure there and abort my program. Can't for the life of my figure out why...I printed out the number totalsLength and its 36, which was the length of the string in textBuffer, which I verified is correct. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

EDIT: New code requested

```
static tNode* newTN(char* string, int sLength, tNode* next){
    tNode* t = malloc(sizeof(struct textNode));
    t->line = malloc(sizeof(char)*sLength);

    if(string != NULL){
        strcpy(t->line, string);
    } 
    t->next = next; 
    return t;
}

TB newTB (char text[]){

    assert(text != NULL); 

    int i = 0; 
    char c;

    TB tBuffer = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer)); 
    tBuffer->size = 0; 

    //tNode* currLine = malloc(sizeof (struct textNode*));
    tNode* currLine = newTN(NULL, 1, NULL);
    tNode* currtNode = NULL; 

    //currLine->line = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while(1){

        c = text[i];

        if(c == '\0'){
            break;
        } else{
            currLine->line = realloc(currLine->line, currLine->sLength+1);
        }

        currLine->line[currLine->sLength] = c;

        if(c == '\n'){ // create new textNode to contain string

            if(tBuffer->size == 0){

                tBuffer->head = newTN(currLine->line, currLine->sLength, NULL);     
                currtNode = tBuffer->head; 

            } else{

                currtNode->next = newTN(currLine->line, currLine->sLength, NULL);
                tBuffer->tail = currtNode->next;
                currtNode = currtNode->next; 
            }

            tBuffer->totalsLength += currLine->sLength+1; //account for \n
            currLine->line = realloc(currLine->line, 0);         
            currLine->sLength = 0;
            tBuffer->size++;
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        currLine->sLength++;
        i++;
    }
    free(currLine->line);
    free(currLine);

    //printBuffer(tBuffer);
    return tBuffer;
}
```

EDIT: adding main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "textbuffer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    TB tb1 = newTB("HI\nHIYO\nHELLO\nwut\nyolo\nugnad\n");

    //swapTB(tb1, 0, 5);

    char* text = dumpTB(tb1);

    int i = 0;
    while(text[i] != 'd'){
        printf("%c", text[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    releaseTB(tb1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the error?

Comment: that should be enough just make sure to pass a text into the array like this:

"hi\nhello\ncomputers\n"

where each bit ends in a '\n' as this represents a line in my tb.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is this enough code to replicate it?

Comment: Hard to replicate without a `main()` function.

Comment: Any time you get any kind of error message from inside the guts of `malloc`, your first hypothesis should be memory corruption and the first thing you should try is running the program under `valgrind`.

Comment: i added a main function.

Comment: Are you sure all the lines have `\n` in them? If a line doesn't have this, you'll read outside the array bounds in the loop.

Comment: Yes each line does. I can print each line successfully after i allocate them into my text buffer. this is just weird because all im doing is allocating 36 bytes of memory and its giving me that error.

Comment: `newTB()` seems overly complex, calling `realloc()` each time through the loop. Use a function like `strchr()` to search for the newline, allocate a string of the appropriate length, and put that in the `tNode`.

Comment: I suggest you step through `newTB` in the debugger, making sure it's allocating and copying everything correctly. It's hard for me to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* text = malloc(sizeof(char) * stringLength+1);
```

Okay, so `text` has `stringLength + 1` accessible bytes.

```
    text[i] = '\n';
```

This is legal if, and only if, `i` is less than or equal to `stringLength`. So lets add some code before it:

```
    if (i > stringLength)
        printf("ACCESS OUT OF BOUNDS: i=%d stringLength=%d\n", i, stringLength);
```

Now let's compile and run it:

> 30
>   ACCESS OUT OF BOUNDS: i=30 stringLength=29
>   31
>   ACCESS OUT OF BOUNDS: i=31 stringLength=29
>   32
>   ACCESS OUT OF BOUNDS: i=32 stringLength=29
>   33
>   ACCESS OUT OF BOUNDS: i=33 stringLength=29
>   ...

Houston, we have a problem.